# Entity Framework performance : SaveChanges isn't caching its execution plans/statements

Tags: performance, entity-framework, savechanges

I'm attempting to performance-tune my application. Having done some profiling it appears that every time I call `SaveChanges()` on my data context (I create a new data context every time an api is executed) it regenerates the commands. I can see it spends a long time in `ProduceCommands`, running the expression builder etc.

Having read the MSDN articles I believed that the commands are created only once then reused, am I wrong? I've moved to using compiled queries for my selects but the updates are killing my performance.

Can anyone offer any advice on how to speed this up? Or is this just an unfortunately slow part of EF?

Many thanks for any advice.